# Reshaping csv with Pandas: joining two subsets of df

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, reshape

My .csv looks like:

```
   Res          X      XB          XC           O       P
  A312      76.55     -           -           -       -  
  B313      175.4   62.28       32.62       8.189   121.2
  J314      176.5   53.34       40.77       8.277   124.6
  L315      177.9   55.29       41.44       8.427   125.5
  T316      174.7   59.47       63.43       8.264   116.1
  ...
  G378      10.2    58.91       40.13       7.646   126.7
```

I would like to reshape it like this:

```
   312 A   X   76.55
   313 B   X   175.4
   313 B   XB  62.28
   313 B   XC  32.62
   ...
   378 G   O   7.646
   378 G   P   126.7
```

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", delim_whitespace = True, index_col = False, na_values = "-")
df2 = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", delim_whitespace = True, index_col = False, na_values = "-")

df1['Pos'] = df1['Res'].str[1:].astype(int)
df1['AA'] = df1['Res'].str[0]
df2.drop('Res', axis = 1, inplace = True)
a = df2.stack(level = -1)
b = df1[["Pos", "AA"]]
print(a)
print(b)
```

this yields:

Output from `print(a)`:

```
0   X      76.500
1   X     175.400
    XB     62.280
    XC     32.620
    O       8.189
    P     121.200
...
62  X      10.200
    XB     58.910
    XC     40.130
    O       7.646
    P     126.700
```

Output from `print(b)`:

```
0   312  A
1   313  B
2   314  J
3   315  L
...
62  378  G
```

Any ideas on how can I make the last step, i.e. joining those two df, `a` and `b`, and finally achieve my desired format? I already tried several `pandas` functionalities, such as `pd.merge`, `pd.join` and `pd.concat`. None of these seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit changed your solution - first added [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column - then `df1.drop('Res', axis = 1, inplace = True)` is not necessary, then create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and call [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last data cleaning - `reset_index` with `rename`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", delim_whitespace = True, index_col = False, na_values = "-")

df1['Pos'] = df1['Res'].str[1:].astype(int)
df1['AA'] = df1.pop('Res').str[0]

df = (df1.set_index(['Pos', 'AA'])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='new')
         .rename(columns={'level_2':'cat'}))
```

---

```
print (df)
    Pos AA cat      new
0   312  A   X   76.550
1   313  B   X  175.400
2   313  B  XB   62.280
3   313  B  XC   32.620
4   313  B   O    8.189
5   313  B   P  121.200
6   314  J   X  176.500
7   314  J  XB   53.340
8   314  J  XC   40.770
9   314  J   O    8.277
10  314  J   P  124.600
11  315  L   X  177.900
12  315  L  XB   55.290
13  315  L  XC   41.440
14  315  L   O    8.427
15  315  L   P  125.500
16  316  T   X  174.700
17  316  T  XB   59.470
18  316  T  XC   63.430
19  316  T   O    8.264
20  316  T   P  116.100
21  378  G   X   10.200
22  378  G  XB   58.910
23  378  G  XC   40.130
24  378  G   O    7.646
25  378  G   P  126.700
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `melt`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv", delim_whitespace=True, index_col=False)

df['Res'] = df['Res'].str[0]
reshaped = df.melt('Res', ['X', 'XB', 'XC', 'O', 'P'])
print(reshaped.dropna().sort_values('Res').reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   Res variable  value
0    A        X  76.55
1    B        O  8.189
2    B        P  121.2
3    B        X  175.4
4    B       XB  62.28
5    B       XC  32.62
6    J        O  8.277
7    J        P  124.6
8    J        X  176.5
9    J       XB  53.34
10   J       XC  40.77
11   L        O  8.427
12   L        P  125.5
13   L        X  177.9
14   L       XB  55.29
15   L       XC  41.44
16   T        O  8.264
17   T        P  116.1
18   T        X  174.7
19   T       XB  59.47
20   T       XC  63.43
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. It indeed seems to be working, but the output is a bit different from what I wanted. By copying your code, what is get is a list (it appears in alphabetic order for "Res", while I would like it to be ordered like the number displayed after the letter in my original table, i.e. A312 ---> 312 A). The alphabetic ordering makes also the variable colums pretty confused!

Comment: @ShawnMarionfan my bad, I misunderstood your expected data.